# Let $f$ be defined as $(f(x))^2=k$ show that $f$ is constant

Tags: calculus, contest-math

Let $f$ be a continious function on $I$ defined as there is a $k\in R$  for every $x\in I$ $(f(x))^2=k$

show that $f$ is constant.

I understand that I have to show that there is a $k'$ for every $x\in I$ such that $f(x)=k'$

What I have tried !

f is continious on $I=(a,b)$ so by the theoriem of borners $f([a,b])=(m,M)$

So $m<f(x)<M$

$f^2$ is continious so $m'<(f(x))^2<M'$

$(f(x))^2$ is constant so there $m'<k<M'$

I am stuck here I want just a hint to do the problem for myself .

Comment: Hint:  if $k=0$ then $f(x)\equiv 0$.If $k>0$ then, for any given $x_0$ $f(x_0)=\pm \sqrt k$.  Suppose we had $f(x_0)=+ \sqrt k$ and $f(x_1)= \, - \sqrt k$, derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

we have $k\geq0$.
if $k=0$ then $f=0$.

assume now $k>0$ and that there exist $a$ and $b$ in the interval $I$, such that

$f(a)=\sqrt{k}$ and $f(b)=-\sqrt{k}$.

$f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ or $[b,a]$, thus there will exist $c \in [a,b]$ or $[b,a]$, such that

$f(c)=0$ using intermediate values theorem.

which is in contradiction with

$f^2(c)=k$.

Comment: "assume k>0". Why? That isn't part of the problem statement.

Comment: if $k=0$ then $f=0$.

Comment: Obviously true -- but it should be stated as part of the proof.